# Why do I need to set padding to 15.5px for both <div> to have equal height?

Tags: html, css

### Code

```css
.topnav {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 6px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.searchbar {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.searchbar input[type=text] {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15.5px;
  outline: none;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.searchbar input[type=text]:hover {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='topnav'>
    <a href='#abcdefg'>abcdefg</a>
  </div>
  <div class='searchbar'>
    <form>
      <input type='text' placeholder='Search here'>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As the title suggests, in order for both `<div class = 'topnav'>` and `<div class = 'searchbar'>` to have the same height, I can set `<div class = 'searchbar'>` padding to 15.5 pixels each.

```
padding: 15.5px;
```

Because of that, I'm having trouble understanding why. That is, I managed to get both`<div>` height to the same size by guessing the right padding, not something I want to be doing. Therefore, **I'm asking for a systematic way to know how much padding I need**.

Comment: I went through my code again and padding only modifies height because I haven't set a fixed height.

Comment: From my computer, both heights seemed the same but they aren't, as the first answer has implicitly pointed out using chrom devtools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if that will be good for you about height exactness... But certainly will easier to tweak. I used a CSS grid an just an additional div as a wrapper.

```css
.topNavContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  grid-template-rows: 53px;
  grid-gap: 6px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 6px solid black;
}

.topnav a {
  padding: 16px 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav a.active,
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.searchbar input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px 0;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}
.searchbar input[type="text"]:hover {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="topNavContainer">
  <div class='topnav'>
    <a href='#abcdefg'>abcdefg</a>
  </div>
  <div class='searchbar'>
    <form>
      <input type='text' placeholder='Search here'>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So I think you're missing that border-box does not include margins (which might have thrown off your calculations). So if you look at the dev tools and remove the 15.5px padding style on you input tag, then scroll to the bottom, you'll see this nice looking thing:

[image]

Yes there is still padding on it, this is from another style (ignore it). Your counterpart div happens to have a height of 64px (on my browser at least), so let's subtract from 64 all the heights (except for the padding, since we will be replacing that) that the dev tools are showing:

64 - 15 - 3  - 3 - 6 - 6 = 31px <- the remaining space

31px / 2 = 15.5px

However, calculations are not ideal either. Specify your heights directly with pixels or percentages, or consider the other answers here.